# Porque está dando erro ao executar o código via Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tendo problemas em executar um código específico através do VScode.
Tenho o Node v4.2.6 instalado e o NPM v3.5.2 e quando vou rodar via Node o código:
let pais = 'Brasil'
console.log(qualquer)
Dá uma mensagem de erro no log:
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let qualquer = 'Legal'
                                                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Esta versão do Node pode não aceitar o “let”, tente usar o var para testar. Algo assim:

```
module.exports = funciona () {  
   ...
   var pais = 'Brasil' 
   console.log(qualquer) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seu Node não aceita let pois ele está numa versão antiga, tente atualizar a versão do node e teste seu código novamente.